# Specialty tree structure - BK Tree

Tags: c++, performance, tree, memory-management

I've been working on a implementation of specialty tree structure called a [BK-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) (more [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) and [here](https://nullwords.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/the-bk-tree-a-data-structure-for-spell-checking/)). Basically, it's a tree that allows relatively efficient querying for items within a specific edit-distance (in my case, [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)).

Anyways, it works, but currently with a tree of ~8 million items, a single query for a hash with an allowable edit-distance of 4 takes ~400 milliseconds on a 2.4 GHz Xeon.

I really want to do some real time things that would greatly benefit from improving that timing, and I'm wondering if any of the smart people here can provide some potential targets for performance improvement.

Source (also on [GitHub](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/deduplicator/bktree.hpp) for easier reading):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdint.h>

// For RWLocks
#include <pthread.h>


namespace BK_Tree_Ns
{
    typedef int64_t hash_type;
    typedef int64_t data_type;

    typedef std::pair<std::set<int64_t>, int64_t> search_ret;
    typedef std::tuple<bool, int64_t, int64_t> rebuild_ret;

    // Search return item. Contains [hash-value, item-data]
    typedef std::pair<hash_type, int64_t> hash_pair;
    typedef std::deque<hash_pair> return_deque;


    int64_t inline f_hamming(int64_t a_int, int64_t b_int);

    /**
     * @brief Compute the hamming distance, e.g. the number of differing
     *        bits between two values, in the fastest manner possible.
     *
     * @param a_int bitfield 1 for distance calculation
     * @param b_int bitfield 2 for distance calculation
     *
     * @return number of differing bits between the two values. Possible
     *         return values are 0-64, as the parameters are 64 bit integers.
     */
    int64_t inline f_hamming(int64_t a_int, int64_t b_int)
    {
        /*
        Compute number of bits that are not common between `a` and `b`.
        return value is a plain integer
        */

        // uint64_t x = (a_int ^ b_int);
        // __asm__(
        //  "popcnt %0 %0  \n\t"// +r means input/output, r means intput
        //  : "+r" (x) );

        // return x;
        uint64_t x = (a_int ^ b_int);

        return __builtin_popcountll (x);

    }



    class BK_Tree_Node
    {
        private:

            /**
             * Bitmapped hash value for the node.
             */
            hash_type                                                 node_hash;

            /**
             * Data values associated with the current node. In my use, they're generally
             * database-ID values as int64_t.
             */
            std::set<data_type>                                       node_data_items;
            // Unordered set is slower for small
            // numbers of n, which we mostly have.

            /**
             * Vector of pointers to children. Non-present children are indicated
             * by a pointer value of NULL, present children are non-NULL.
             * Vector size is 65, for an allowable edit-distance range of
             * 0-64 (0 is functionally not used).
             */
            std::vector<BK_Tree_Node *>                                children;

            /**
             * @brief Internal item removal function. Removes a hash-data pair from the tree
             *        and does any associated required tree-rebuilding that is required
             *        as a function of the changes.
             *
             * @detail Note that re-insertion of parentless-nodes is actually handled by
             *         BK_Tree_Node::remove, as it made the architecture design considerably
             *         simpler, and node removal is not often done.
             *         Rather then trying to do in-place re-insertion as soon as a valid parent
             *         is reached, they're simply all propigated back up to the root node
             *         and re-inserted from there, because that way there only
             *         has to be a single point where re-insertion is done, and it can
             *         use the same code-paths as normal insertion.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash to search for.
             * @param nodeData data associated with hash.
             * @param ret_deq reference to a `return_deque` into which any parentless-node's data
             *                is copied into for re-insertion.
             * @return std::vector<int64_t> containing 3 status values.
             *         The first is a boolean cast to an int, indicating
             *         whether the direct child node is empty, and should
             *         be deleted (with it's children re-inserted).
             *
             *         The second is a count of the number of children
             *         that were actually deleted by the remove call (which
             *         should really only ever be 1).
             *         The third is the number of child-nodes that had to be re-inserted to
             *         accomodate any deletion of any nodes.
             */
            rebuild_ret remove_internal(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData, return_deque &ret_deq)
            {
                // Remove node with hash `nodeHash` and accompanying data `nodeData` from the tree.
                // Returns list of children that must be re-inserted (or false if no children need to be updated),
                // number of nodes deleted, and number of nodes that were moved as a 3-tuple.

                int64_t deleted = 0;
                int64_t moved   = 0;

                // If the node we're on matches the hash we want to delete exactly:
                if (nodeHash == this->node_hash)
                {
                    // Validate we have the
                    if (this->node_data_items.count(nodeData) > 0)
                    {
                        // Remove the node data associated with the hash we want to remove
                        this->node_data_items.erase(nodeData);
                    }

                    // If we've emptied out the node of data, return all our children so the parent can
                    // graft the children into the tree in the appropriate place
                    if (this->node_data_items.size() == 0)
                    {
                        // 1 deleted node, 0 moved nodes, return all children for reinsertion by parent
                        // Parent will pop this node, and reinsert all it's children where apropriate
                        this->get_contains(ret_deq);
                        return rebuild_ret(true, 1, 0);
                    }
                    // node has data remaining, do not do any rebuilding
                    return rebuild_ret(false, 1, 0);
                }

                int64_t selfDist = f_hamming(this->node_hash, nodeHash);

                // Removing is basically searching with a distance of zero, and
                // then doing operations on the search result.
                // As such, scan children where the edit distance between `self.nodeHash` and the target `nodeHash` == 0
                // Rebuild children where needed
                if (this->children[selfDist] != NULL)
                {
                    rebuild_ret removed = this->children[selfDist]->remove_internal(nodeHash, nodeData, ret_deq);

                    bool remove_child = std::get<0>(removed);
                    deleted          += std::get<1>(removed);
                    moved            += std::get<2>(removed);

                    // If the child returns children, it means the child no longer contains any unique data, so it
                    // needs to be deleted. As such, pop it from the tree
                    // It's children will be re-inserted as the last step in removal.
                    if (remove_child)
                    {
                        delete this->children[selfDist];
                        this->children[selfDist] = NULL;
                    }
                }
                return rebuild_ret(false, deleted, moved);
            }


            /**
             * @brief Recursively find and insert a hash-data pair into the proper
             *        node, creating it if necessary.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash for data that is being inserted.
             * @param nodeData data that accompanies inserted hash.
             */
            void insert_internal(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData)
            {
                // If the current node has the same hash as the data we're inserting,
                // add the data to the current node's data set
                if (nodeHash == this->node_hash)
                {
                    this->node_data_items.insert(nodeData);
                    return;
                }

                // otherwise, calculate the edit distance between the new phash and the current node's hash,
                // and either recursively insert the data, or create a new child node for the phash
                int distance = f_hamming(this->node_hash, nodeHash);


                if (this->children[distance] != NULL) // If we have a node, descend into it and try inserting it there.
                {
                    this->children[distance]->insert(nodeHash, nodeData);
                }
                else // Otherwise, construct the new node for the data.
                {
                    // Construct in-place for extra fancyness
                    this->children[distance] = new BK_Tree_Node(nodeHash, nodeData);
                }

            }


            /**
             * @brief Internals: Search function.
             * @details Searches tree recursively for items within `distance` hamming
             *          edit distance of `search_hash`. Found items are written into
             *          the `&search_ret` reference.
             *
             * @param search_hash base hash to use for searching.
             * @param distance Edit distance to search.
             * @param ret Reference to deque into which found results are placed.
             */
            void search_internal(hash_type search_hash, int64_t distance, search_ret &ret)
            {
                int64_t selfDist = f_hamming(this->node_hash, search_hash);

                // Add self values if the current node is within the proper distance.
                if (selfDist <= distance)
                    for (const data_type &val: this->node_data_items)
                        ret.first.insert(val);

                ret.second += 1;

                // Search scope is self_distance - search_distance <-> self_distance + search_distance,
                // as hamming distance is a metric space and obeys triangle inequalities.
                // We also clamp the search space to the bounds of our
                // index.
                int64_t posDelta = std::min((selfDist + distance), static_cast<int64_t>(64));
                int64_t negDelta = std::max((selfDist - distance), static_cast<int64_t>(0));

                // For each child within our search scope, if the child is present (non-NULL),
                // recursively search into that child.
                for (int_fast8_t x = negDelta; x <= posDelta; x += 1)
                {
                    if (this->children[x] != NULL)
                    {
                        this->children[x]->search_internal(search_hash, distance, ret);
                    }
                }

            }


        public:
            /**
             * @brief Create a BK_Tree_Node containing the specified hash and data pair.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash for node.
             * @param node_data data associated with hash.
             */
            BK_Tree_Node(hash_type nodeHash, int64_t node_data)
            {
                // std::cout << "Instantiating BK_Tree_Node instance - Hash: " << nodeHash << " node_data: " << node_data << std::endl;
                this->node_data_items.insert(node_data);
                this->node_hash = nodeHash;

                // Child 0 is unused, because if the distance between the
                // current hash and the node hash is 0, it'll just be inserted onto the current
                // node's data.
                // We use a 65-ary tree just so the math is easier, leaking 8 bytes per node is kind of
                // irrelevant (I hope).
                this->children.assign(65, NULL);

            }

            /**
             * @brief Delete a node. This will explicitly delete any
             *        children of the node as well.
             */
            ~BK_Tree_Node()
            {
                for (auto val: this->children)
                {
                    if (val != NULL)
                        delete val;
                }
            }

            /**
             * @brief Insert a hash<->data pair into the tree.
             * @details Inserts a hash<->data pair into the tree.
             *
             * @param nodeHash node-hash to insert.
             * @param nodeData data associated with the node-hash.
             */
            void insert(hash_type nodeHash, int64_t nodeData)
            {
                this->insert_internal(nodeHash, nodeData);
            }


            /**
             * @brief Given the hash and data-value for a item,
             *        find and remove it from the tree.
             * @details Removes an item from the tree by hash and
             *          id. This may involve reconstructing up to
             *          the entire tree, in a worst-case circumstance.
             *
             *          If the specified hash<->data pair is not found,
             *          nothing will be done, and no error will be raised.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash to remove
             * @param nodeData id to remove
             *
             * @return std::vector<int64_t> containing 3 status values.
             *         The first is a boolean cast to an int, indicating
             *         whether the direct child node is empty, and should
             *         be deleted (with it's children re-inserted).
             *
             *         The second is a count of the number of children
             *         that were actually deleted by the remove call (which
             *         should really only ever be 1).
             *         The third is the number of child-nodes that had to be re-inserted to
             *         accomodate any deletion of any nodes.
             */
            std::vector<int64_t> remove(hash_type nodeHash, int64_t nodeData)
            {
                // Remove the matching hash. Insert any items that need to be re-added
                // into a deque for processing.
                return_deque ret_deq;
                auto rm_status = this->remove_internal(nodeHash, nodeData, ret_deq);


                int non_null_children = 0;
                for (size_t x = 0; x < this->children.size(); x += 1)
                    if (this->children[x] != NULL)
                        non_null_children += 1;

                // if the current node is empty, pull the first item from the new item list, and
                // set the current node to it's contained values.
                if (this->node_data_items.size() == 0 && ret_deq.empty() == false)
                {
                    assert(non_null_children == 0);

                    hash_pair new_root_content = ret_deq.front();
                    ret_deq.pop_front();
                    this->node_hash = new_root_content.first;
                    this->node_data_items.insert(new_root_content.second);
                }

                // Rebuild any tree leaves that were damaged by the remove operation
                // by re-inserting their contents.
                for (const hash_pair i: ret_deq)
                    this->insert(i.first, i.second);


                // Pack up the return value.
                std::vector<int64_t> ret;
                ret.push_back(1 ? std::get<0>(rm_status) : 0);
                ret.push_back(std::get<1>(rm_status));
                ret.push_back(std::get<2>(rm_status));

                return ret;

            }

            /**
             * @brief Search the tree for items within a
             *        certain distance of a specified hash.
             * @details Searches the tree recursively for
             *          all items within a specified hamming distance
             *          of the passed parameter.
             *
             * @param baseHash Hash-value to find items similar to.
             * @param distance Maximum allowed Hamming distance between
             *                 the specified hash and returned
             *                 similar values.
             *
             * @return std::pair<std::set<int64_t>, int64_t>, where the
             *         first item is a set of item_id values for each matched
             *         similar items, and the second value is the number
             *         of tree nodes the search had to touch to return
             *         the first value (for diagnostic purposes).
             */
            search_ret search(hash_type baseHash, int distance)
            {
                search_ret ret;
                ret.second = 0;
                this->search_internal(baseHash, distance, ret);
                return ret;
            }

            /**
             * @brief Get all items in tree
             * @details Fetches all contained items in the tree into
             *          a `return_deque` passed by reference.
             *          This is a non-destructive operation, it makes no changes to the
             *          tree.
             *
             * @param ret_deq Reference to a deque<hash_pair>, where has_pair is
             *                a std::pair<hash_type, int64_t> containing the item hash
             *                and the item id respectively.
             */
            void get_contains(return_deque &ret_deq)
            {
                // For each item the node contains, push it back into the dequeu
                for (const int64_t i : this->node_data_items)
                    ret_deq.push_back(hash_pair(this->node_hash, i));

                // Then, iterate over the item's children.
                for (const auto val : this->children)
                    if (val != NULL)
                        val->get_contains(ret_deq);

            }



    };


    /**
     * @brief General use-class for managing a tree of BK_Tree_Node nodes.
     *        Provides parallel-access locking.
     *
     */
    class BK_Tree
    {
        private:
            BK_Tree_Node      tree;
            pthread_rwlock_t lock_rw;


        public:

            /**
             * @brief Construct a BK_Tree starting with specified node_values.
             *        Also sets up the required RW locks an associated plumbing.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash-value for the root of the tree.
             * @param node_id associated data-value for the tree root.
             */
            BK_Tree(hash_type nodeHash, data_type node_id)
                : tree(nodeHash, node_id)
            {
                this->lock_rw = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;
                int ret = pthread_rwlock_init(&(this->lock_rw), NULL);
                if (ret != 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error initializing pthread rwlock!" << std::endl;
                }
                assert(ret == 0);
            }

            ~BK_Tree()
            {
                // std::cout << "Destroying BK_Tree instance" << std::endl;
            }

            /**
             * @brief Insert an hash-data pair into the BK tree with proper write-locking.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash to insert
             * @param nodeData data associated with the hash value.
             */
            void insert(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData)
            {
                this->get_write_lock();
                this->tree.insert(nodeHash, nodeData);
                this->free_write_lock();
            }

            /**
             * @brief Insert an hash-data pair into the BK tree without taking out
             *        a write lock. POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS. This is only intended to be
             *        used for high-speed initial population of the tree, where the user
             *        manages the locking a higher-level (via `get_write_lock()`).
             *
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash to insert
             * @param nodeData data associated with the hash value.
             */
            void unlocked_insert(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData)
            {
                this->tree.insert(nodeHash, nodeData);
            }


            /**
             * @brief Given the hash and data-value for a item,
             *        find and remove it from the tree.
             * @details Removes an item from the tree by hash and
             *          id. This may involve reconstructing up to
             *          the entire tree, in a worst-case circumstance.
             *
             *          If the specified hash<->data pair is not found,
             *          nothing will be done, and no error will be raised.
             *
             * @param nodeHash hash to remove
             * @param nodeData id to remove
             *
             * @return std::vector<int64_t> containing 2 status values.
             *         The first is a count of the number of children
             *         that were actually deleted by the remove call (which
             *         should really only ever be 1).
             *         The second is the number of child-nodes that had to be re-inserted to
             *         accomodate any deletion of any nodes.
             */
            std::vector<int64_t> remove(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData)
            {
                this->get_write_lock();
                auto rm_status = this->tree.remove(nodeHash, nodeData);

                // bool rebuild = rm_status[0]; // Rebuilding is handled in tree.remove()
                int deleted  = rm_status[1];
                int moved    = rm_status[2];

                this->free_write_lock();
                std::vector<int64_t> ret(2);
                ret[0] = deleted;
                ret[1] = moved;
                return ret;
            }

            /**
             * @brief Fetch all data values within a specified hamming distance
             *        of the specified hash.
             *
             * @param baseHash hash value for the distance benchmark.
             * @param distance hamming distance to search within.
             *
             * @return std::pair<std::set<int64_t>, <int64_t>, where
             *         the first item is a set of data-values for
             *         hashes within the specified distance, and
             *         the second is the number of tree nodes touched
             *         during the search (for diagnostic purposes).
             */
            search_ret getWithinDistance(hash_type baseHash, int distance)
            {
                // std::cout << "Get within distance!" << std::endl;
                this->get_read_lock();
                auto ret = this->tree.search(baseHash, distance);
                this->free_read_lock();
                return ret;
            }

            /**
             * @brief Get all items in the tree. Mostly for testing.
             * @return std::deque<std::pair<hash_type, int64_t> > containing every
             *         hash<->data pair in the entire tree.
             *         Largely useful for unit testing, and probably not much else.
             */
            return_deque get_all(void)
            {
                return_deque ret;
                this->get_read_lock();
                this->tree.get_contains(ret);
                this->free_read_lock();
                return ret;
            }

            /**
             * @brief Proxy calls to the lock mechanisms, exposed
             *        so higher-level interfaces can do high-speed operations where they manage their
             *        own locks.
             */

            void get_read_lock(void)
            {
                pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&(this->lock_rw));
            }
            void get_write_lock(void)
            {
                pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&(this->lock_rw));
            }

            void free_read_lock(void)
            {
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&(this->lock_rw));
            }
            void free_write_lock(void)
            {
                pthread_rwlock_unlock(&(this->lock_rw));
            }


    };


}
```

The C++ implementation is actually a re-implementation of a Cython implementation ([here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/deduplicator/cyHamDb.pyx#L130-L257)), which interestingly enough is about as fast as the C++ (it's ~10% slower, in some primitive benchmarking), so I suspect I'm basically being killed by cache-misses, and I'm not sure if there is much room for any actual improvements (aside from parallel readers, which I'm already working on).

Anyways, profiling:

[image]
<sup>I haven't figured out how to convince `callgrind` to output text reports</sup>

From the above, ~60% of the execution time is spent in `bk_tree::BK_Tree_Node::search_internal()`, which I'd expect. ~20% is eaten by my test-harness and the associated Python->C++ calling overhead, and the rest is heavily scattered everywhere else.

Using `callgrind`'s line profiler, I get a rather odd report, and I'm not sure if it's an artifact or not:

[image]

This seems to indicate that 20%(!) of my execution time is spent just on the overhead of a simple loop, and an additional 26% is in null-checking the items within the search scope.

This makes *some* sense, as this is a recursive call, and the assumed overhead to `search_internal()` isn't shown, as it's just calling itself, but the loop overhead seems somewhat outlandish to me. I can understand the overhead of the null check (that's where I'd expect the cache miss to happen).

You can see a bit of my experimentation trying to understand why the loop is the slow component (`int_fast8` for the loop counter, it used to be a standard `int`. The change didn't make much of a difference).

I can imagine this being an effect of the profiler (I'm using vallgrind/callgrind for this profiling), but I don't understand why.

---

Using `cachegrind` to inspect for cache locality issues:

> ```
> ==22001==
> ==22001== I   refs:      11,354,026,385
> ==22001== I1  misses:       119,392,163
> ==22001== LLi misses:           546,930
> ==22001== I1  miss rate:           1.05%
> ==22001== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
> ==22001==
> ==22001== D   refs:       5,331,362,545  (3,819,834,434 rd   + 1,511,528,111 wr)
> ==22001== D1  misses:       183,832,198  (  168,040,186 rd   +    15,792,012 wr)
> ==22001== LLd misses:       136,489,157  (  125,659,115 rd   +    10,830,042 wr)
> ==22001== D1  miss rate:            3.4% (          4.3%     +           1.0%  )
> ==22001== LLd miss rate:            2.5% (          3.2%     +           0.7%  )
> ==22001==
> ==22001== LL refs:          303,224,361  (  287,432,349 rd   +    15,792,012 wr)
> ==22001== LL misses:        137,036,087  (  126,206,045 rd   +    10,830,042 wr)
> ==22001== LL miss rate:             0.8% (          0.8%     +           0.7%  )
> ```

I confess I'm not too sure how to interpret this, aside from the fact that it looks like I'm generally hitting the cache more then I'm missing, but I don't have a functional intuitive grasp of the costs of cache misses, so it may be horrible and I just don't know it.

---

Edit: Benchmarks!

There is now a [benchmarking script](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/perf-testing/cbench.cpp) in the repo (script for building [here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/perf-testing/build_bench.sh)).

It builds a 8000000 node test-tree, and then does 1000 test queries against it. I'm using the [hayai benchmarking framework](https://github.com/nickbruun/hayai) (You may need to install it).

Note that the test requires ~5.1 GB of RAM, so it requires a 64 bit architecture.

[image]

---

Notes: I'm using a mix of `underscore_name` and `TitleCased` variables. Yes, I'm a bad person.

At least it doesn't leak memory, according to valgrind.

Comment: How many of your `children[x]` nodes are NULL?  Probably a lot, and you walk the entire tree in your search.  The code spends roughly 20x as much time in your `for` loop as it does doing the simple comparison (`selfdist <= distance`), so if your search distance is 10 (so each function call will loop ~21 times) those could be reasonable numbers.  What kind of call counts are you getting on those lines?  And a small tweak:  Since you're not using `children[0]`, `negDelta` can start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: A benchmark/test would help. Is there anything in the repo for that?

Comment: Would C++14 be ok? Or C++11 at least?

Comment: @nwp - It's already C++11. C++14 should be fine. As long as I can build it with GCC 4.8.4 (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and I don't want to have to install additional compilers)

Comment: @Mat - There's one in the [github repo](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/profile_bk.py#L80-L90), but it's done through cython, so I'm not sure if it's really compact enough to refer other people to. Let me see if I can throw something together

Comment: @Mat - C++ only benchmarking interface/test now up.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - That's a good point about `negDelta`! Doh! Fixed. Incidentally, my normal search distance is 2-4, occasionally 6. For the profiling in the post it's 4.

Comment: @nwp - Ok, the version of GCC I have doesn't support C++14, through I'd be willing to upgrade if there is a compelling reason. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

## Miscellaneous things

- Prefer `using` over `typedef`. Aliases created using the former are a bit easier to read.
- If you do use type aliases, use them consistently. There are some cases where you still use `int64_t`.
- Don't use `std::pair` and `std::tuple` if you can just create your own `struct`; the latter will have *named* members, which helps document the code and avoids you from having to remember the exact order. It avoids the ugly `std::get<>`s.
- Avoid forward declarations. The one for `f_hamming()` is useless anyway, as it is just above its definition. Not repeating yourself saves writing code and prevents mistakes (a typo in one could cause an overload to be created without any warning).
- Unnecessary use of `this->`. You almost never have to write `this->` in C++, and mostly it just adds noise to the code, so I would remove it.
- Write `++x` instead of `x += 1`. The former is more idiomatic.
- You can omit `void` in the parameter list of functions that take no parameters, for example: `void get_read_lock() {...}`
- [Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n).

## Naming things

Inside `BK_Tree`, write `head` instead of `tree`.

## Use a `std::array` for `children`

Since `children` has a fixed size, use `std::array` for it:

```
std::array<BK_Tree_Node *, 65> children;
```

This avoids a memory allocation, and might allow some compiler optimizations as well.

## Avoid manual memory allocations

Instead of manually calling `new` and `delete`, prefer using smart pointers or STL containers to handle allocations for you. In this case, use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for pointers to children:

```
class BK_Tree_Node
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<BK_Tree_Node>, 65> children;
    ...
public:
    BK_Tree_Node(hash_type nodeHash, data_type node_data):
        node_hash(nodeHash), node_data(nodeData) {}

    ~BK_Tree_Node() = default; // This line can be removed
    ...
    void remove_internal(...) {
        ...
        // Delete an existing node
        children[selfDist].reset();
        ...
    }

    void insert_internal(hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData) {
        ...
        // Construct a new node
        children[distance] = std::make_unique<BK_Tree_Node>(nodeHash, nodeData);
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

## Locking

I see you made your tree thread-safe by adding a read-write lock. There are several issues with this. First, it penalizes any caller who wants to use a BK-tree in a single-threaded situation. You could instead not lock at all, and leave that up to the caller. This frees your code from that responsibility, making it both easier to maintain and more versatile, although it of course loses its convenience when you do need it to be thread-safe.

The second issue is that `pthread_rwlock_t` and related functions are POSIX, but not part of the C or C++ standard. They are also a bit unsafe to use; consider an exception being thrown while a lock was held. It is much better to make use of [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to lock it.
Since C++17 there is also [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) which provides the same semantics as `pthread_rwlock_t`.

Avoid APIs that can potentially be misused. I can see why you want to allow efficient bulk inserts, but now the caller has to call `get_write_lock()`, then `unlocked_insert()` multiple times, and then remember to `free_write_lock()`. Also, why is there `get_read_lock()` if there is no unlocked getter? A better interface would be one that lets `BK_Tree` still take care of locking. You could do that by inversion of control:

```
class BK_Tree
{
    ...
public:
    using insert_function = std::function<void(hash_type, data_type)>;

    void bulk_insert(std::function<void(insert_function)> callback) {
        get_write_lock();
        callback([&](hash_type nodeHash, data_type nodeData) {
            tree.insert(nodeHash, nodeData);
        });
        free_write_lock();
    }
    ...
};
```

The caller could then use it like so:

```
BK_Tree_Ns::BK_Tree tree;

std::mt19937_64 generator;
generator.seed(12345);

tree.bulk_insert([&](auto insert) {
    for (int x = 1; x < TEST_TREE_SIZE; x += 1)
        insert(generator(), x);
    }
});
```

Or by letting the caller provide you with anything you can iterate over:

```
class BK_Tree
{
    ...
public:
    template<typename Range>
    void bulk_insert(const Range& range) {
        get_write_lock();
        for (auto [nodeHash, nodeData]: range) {
            tree.insert(nodeHash, nodeData);
        }
        free_write_lock();
    }
};
```

## Memory usage

With 8 million entries, your BK-tree indeed uses about 5 gigabytes of memory. That's quite a lot! Consider that at most levels of the tree, you will have much less than 64 children, you can save a lot of memory. Also consider that most nodes will be leaf nodes, and thus won't need any child pointers!

Furthermore, each memory allocation comes with its own overhead. For 8 million entries, you have 8 million individual memory allocations. It would be nicer to pack multiple nodes close together in bigger allocations. Consider using a [`std::deque<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) to hold children by value:

```
class BK_Tree_Node
{
    std::deque<BK_Tree_Node> children;
    ...
};
```

And don't preallocate 65 entries in `children`; for leaf nodes this avoids any further allocations, and for internal nodes where you don't have 65 non-null pointers, it saves memory.

## Performance

Following child pointers, as seen in the per-line profile output, is indeed what I would expect. Especially if your data is spread out over 5 gigabytes, it will definitely not fit into the L2 cache, although a Xeon might have enough L3. Given that you have to check about 100000 nodes for each query, times a roughly 50 cycle L3 access latency, that is already 2.4 milliseconds at 2.4 GHz in the best case, and does not include any of the other work that has to be done. Your screenshot of the benchmarking results shows it takes about 40 ms per iteration, which would mean about 960 cycles per node visited. That sounds a bit slow, and would warrant further investigation. Consider using [Linux perf](https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) on your benchmark binary, and instead of just looking for cycles spent, you can also tell perf to count cache misses, branch misses and other interesting events. Make sure the benchmark runs long enough to get enough samples though.

Comment: OT: `Unnecessary use of this->. You almost never have to write this-> in C++, and mostly it just adds noise to the code, so I would remove it.` I regard the implicit this in C++ as one of the language's *worst* features, and I refuse to ever write code that uses it.

Comment: `Write ++x instead of x += 1. The former is more idiomatic.` I disagree about it being idiomatic, and I think it's much less readable.

Comment: It is fine to have your own preferences for how you program, I have some of my own as well. But in a code review I'll compare your code against the general "best" practices used by the larger C++ community. The risk of deviating too much from those, even if your code is otherwise valid, is that it makes harder for other people to read or contribute to your code, something to keep in mind if you want to expose your project to the general public. Also, "I refuse to ever write code that [...]" might prevent you from being able to contribute to other projects or work in a team.